# Is $S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $$S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}},{\space}n\geq2$$ 
Is this series convergent as $n\to\infty$?

$\mathbf{My{\space}Tries}$

The first idea comes to my mind is to prove that this sequence is actually a Cauchy  Sequence, however it failed because I found that (just skip the calculation)$$|S_m-S_n|<\sqrt{\frac{m}{n-1}}$$

And then I'm stuck here, since I can not find a upper bound for $\sqrt{\frac{m}{n-1}}$.

Then I resorted to some other convergence tests, like the Ratio test. However, I found these tests are not necessarily available in this situation because as $n\to\infty$, the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ also affects the behavior of $S_n$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is possible.

Finally, I just simulated this series on R and it seems to be convergent. Is there any rigorous idea that can be applied to prove this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Stolz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=2.$$

Comment: Brilliant! I totally forgot this theorem even I previously proved this.

Answer (score 4):

Basically the integral test for convergence.

$$\frac{2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx\leq S_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac{2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1})}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Taking limits we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already received good answers about the limit, let me show that we can have quite good *approximations* of the partial terms.

If you are familiar with generalized harmonic numbers, we have
$$\sqrt{n}\,S_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+1}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-1$$ Using the asymptotics of the rhs would then give
$$S_n=2+ \left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{2
   n}-\frac{1}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Using for $n=10$, the exact value would be $1.2715512$ while the above truncated expansion would give $1.2715509$.